# how to append a list to another list using for loop

Tags: python, list

```
 def divinding(a):
    b=[]
    c=[]
    a.sort()
    for i in a:
        if(i%a[0])==0:
            b.append(i)
        else:
            pass
    if(len(b)>2):
        store(b)
    else:
        pass
    if(len(a)>1):
        a.pop(0)
        divinding(a)

def store(b):
    c=[]
    c.append(b)
    print c
divinding([2, 11, 16, 12, 36, 60, 71, 17, 29, 144, 288, 129, 432, 993])
```

in this code a get all values seperately

```
[[2, 12, 16, 36, 60, 144, 288, 432]],[[12, 36, 60, 144, 288, 432]],[[16, 144, 288, 432]],[[36, 144, 288, 432]],[[144, 288, 432]]
```

but i need all values in a single list

```
[2, 12, 16, 36, 60, 144, 288, 432],[12, 36, 60, 144, 288, 432],[16, 144, 288, 432],[36, 144, 288, 432],[144, 288, 432]
```

like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need that `store` function at all; all it does it wrap `b` into `c` and then print `c`. Instead, I suggest adding `b` to `c` directly in `divinding` [sic]. Use `append` to add `b`, and `extend` to add all the elements from the `c` returned by the recursive call to `dividing(a)` after `a.pop(0)`.

```
def dividing(a):
    c = []
    a.sort()
    b = [i for i in a if i % a[0] == 0]
    if len(b) > 2:
        c.append(b)
    if len(a) > 1:
        a.pop(0)
        c.extend(dividing(a))
    return c
```

The result is now not printed directly by the function, but returned:

```
>>> result = dividing([2, 11, 16, 12, 36, 60, 71, 17, 29, 144, 288, 129, 432, 993])
>>> print result
[[2, 12, 16, 36, 60, 144, 288, 432], [12, 36, 60, 144, 288, 432], [16, 144, 288, 432], [36, 144, 288, 432], [144, 288, 432]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Define 'c' outside the store function, for example

```
c = []

def store(b):
    c.append(b)
```

Output is:

```
c

Out[11]: [[2, 12, 16, 36, 60, 144, 288, 432],[12, 36, 60, 144, 288, 432],[16, 144, 288, 432],[36, 144, 288, 432],[144, 288, 432]]
```

Comment: Note that this will yield funny results if the function is called more than once.